# How to create a Type from all string attributes of a type in typescript

Tags: typescript

Say I have a type:

```js
type Foo = {
    a : number
    b : string
    c : number
    d : string
}
```

And I want to be able to construct a type such as `type Bar = AllStringAttributes<Foo>` which would return a new type:

```
type Bar = {
    b : string
    d : string
}
```

This is pretty easy, such as with the type

```
type KeysOfValue<T, TCondition> = {
    [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends TCondition
      ? K
      : never;
  }[keyof T];

type Bar = KeysOfValue<Foo, string>;
```

Code taken from [here](https://www.totaltypescript.com/get-keys-of-an-object-where-values-are-of-a-given-type)

But this approach does not work for nested objects. How can I get for example:

```js
type Bazz = {
  inner : {
     a : number,
     b : string,
  }
}
```

And get a type which equals `"inner.b"`

Comment: See `DeepKeysMatching` from the other question, or use [this version](https://tsplay.dev/WY52rW).